# Call stored procedure with table-valued parameter from java

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, parameters

In my application I want to execute query like **SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col IN (@list)** where,@list can have variable no of values. I am using MS SQL server database. When I google this problem then I found this link

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

This link says to use table-valued parameter. So I created user-defined data type using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

**CREATE TYPE integer_list_tbltype AS TABLE (n int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)**

Then I wrote stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_product_names @prodids integer_list_tbltype READONLY AS
   SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName
   FROM   Northwind.dbo.Products p
   WHERE  p.ProductID IN (SELECT n FROM @prodids)
```

and then using management studio only I executed this procedure

```
DECLARE @mylist integer_list_tbltype
INSERT @mylist(n) VALUES(9),(12),(27),(37)
EXEC get_product_names @mylist
```

and it is giving me correct output. But I am wondering how to call this stored procedure from java source code. I know how to call simple stored procedure with constant number of argument

```
CallableStatement proc_stmt = null;
proc_stmt = con.prepareCall("{call test(?)}");
proc_stmt.setString(1,someValue);
```

but how to call stored procedure in table-value parameter case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass Table-Valued Parameters (Array-like Parameter) to Stored Procedure in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 using JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502410/how-to-pass-table-valued-parameters-array-like-parameter-to-stored-procedure-i)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters

Answer (score -7, accepted):

After searching for a while I found answer of this problem.Specially when you use IN clause and no of operands are variable then you can use comma-delimited values as an input in IN clause.

Here's the example how the stored procedure that will retrieve all lawyers of the given lawyer type in the provided ZIP code will look like using dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLawyers] ( @ZIP CHAR(5), @LawyerTypeIDs VARCHAR(100) )
AS

DECLARE @SQL     VARCHAR(2000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Lawyers]
            WHERE [ZIP] = ' + @ZIP + ' AND
                  [LawyerTypeID] IN (' + @LawyerTypeIDs + ')'
EXECUTE (@SQL)

GO
```

To execute the stored procedure passing the ZIP code entered by the user and the selected lawyer types in a comma separated value:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[GetLawyers] '12345', '1,4'
```

So conclusion is you do not need to use TVP. Whichever language[Java, PHP] you use just pass parameters as comma-delimited string to stored procedure and it will work perfect.

So in JAVA you can call above stored procedure:-

```
proc_stmt = con.prepareCall("{call GetLawyers(?,?)}");
proc_stmt.setString(1,"12345");
proc_stmt.setString(2,"'1,4'");
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it may fill up the statement cache.

Comment: @ngund Hi, I tried this solution, and If I understood it well, I did the following: m_cStatement.setString("'1,2,3'")); and then I got the following exception: "Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with udt_UsersById". Can you advise please? (I posted a question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161789/what-is-the-java-equivalent-to-sql-user-defined-table-type and it was marked as duplicated. Can you take a look please?) 10X!

Comment: The problem with this is it could open you up to sql injection

Comment: How about setting the `@ZIP` parameter to `"0; DROP TABLE [Lawyers]; --"`

Answer (score 8):

This is documented here in the [JDBC driver manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt651781(v=sql.110).aspx). In your case, you'd have to do this:

```
try (SQLServerCallableStatement stmt =
    (SQLServerCallableStatement) con.prepareCall("{call test(?)}")) {

    SQLServerDataTable table = new SQLServerDataTable();   
    sourceDataTable.addColumnMetadata("n", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);   

    sourceDataTable.addRow(9);
    sourceDataTable.addRow(12);
    sourceDataTable.addRow(27);
    sourceDataTable.addRow(37);

    stmt.setStructured(1, "dbo.integer_list_tbltype", table);  
}
```

[I've also recently documented this in an article](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/10/jooq-3-10-will-support-sql-servers-table-valued-parameters/).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is a planned addition to JDBC but has not been implemented yet:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/04/03/how-would-you-use-table-valued-parameters-tvp.aspx

Pass the parameter as a delimited string ("9,12,27,37") and then create a table-valued function in SQL Server called "fnSplit" or whatever that will return the integer values in a table (just search for "sql server split function," there are millions of them).

Comment: thank you @Kevin. Do you know any solution other than using TVP for problem.

Comment: Hi Pranay, You are welcome. Check my original answer for suggestion.  Pass delimited string as single parameter of type varchar(max).  Then, inside your stored proc, call SQL Server Split user-defined function (you will need to create this, just search for it, you will find plenty of help).  "Split" function should return a table from a delimited string.  Good luck.

Comment: Just to add to @Kevin's helpful answer, the OP's original link includes an example of a function called "iter_intlist_to_tbl" to split the varchar into a table variable (http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#iterative)! Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: We are in 2015. Is the situation still the same? Is this support still missing?

Comment: @MárioMeyrelles - Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server now supports table-type parameters. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41977740/2144390) for details.

Answer (score 2):

The typical answers (comma delimited or XML) all have problems with SQL Injection.  I needed an answer that allows me to use a PreparedStatement.  So I came up with this:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append(
  "DECLARE @mylist integer_list_tbltype;" +
  "INSERT @mylist(n) VALUES(?)");
for (int i = 0; i < values.size() - 1; ++i) {
  query.append(",(?) ");
}
query.append("; EXEC get_product_names @mylist ");
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
    preparedStmt.setObject(i + 1, itemLookupValues.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now it's been added to JDBC Driver 6.0.
It CTP2 yet.

"This new driver now supports Table-Valued Parameters and Azure Active Directory. In addition to these new features, we have added additionally functionality for Always Encrypted. The driver also supports Internationalized Domain Names and Parameterized."

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2016/04/04/get-the-new-microsoft-jdbc-driver-6-0-preview/

Download link:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

Here is the documentation how to use it 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt651781(v=sql.110).aspx