# Using TVP with SQL Server stored procedure (java)

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I need to call from my Java class that looks like this:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_deleteData]
@tvpData As [dbo].[udt_deletedData] Readonly

AS
BEGIN
    DELETE  x
    FROM    dbo.Table1 AS x 
    INNER JOIN @tvpData AS y
    ON      y.ID= x.ID;
END
```

In .NET, I can take a DataTable object and pass it into the stored procedure - no problem. I've had problems finding anything that is the equivalent in Java:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/04/03/how-would-you-use-table-valued-parameters-tvp.aspx

Should I pass a list and turn it into a data table on the proc end? How would I do this? Please tell me I am bad at the Googles and there is a solution :(

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047818/call-stored-procedure-with-table-valued-parameter-from-java But to answer your question: you'll probably have to pass your parameters as comma seperated list and use splitString function. Here's a very detailed article about them: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: I'd be inclined to pass an XML parameter rather than a delimited list, it gives you greater flexibility, e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1398

Comment: Just out of curiousity, I always thought XMLs are quite resource-hungry in SQL Server?

Comment: No more so than a split function. In the article you have linked to one of the best performing solutions is using xml by turning the comma delimited string into xml before splitting it. Having an xml parameter just cuts out the middle man

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this article before you name your procedures. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Thanks for the article Sean.